# EFI boot and Grub setting for a system with 2 different Ubuntu distributions - configuration

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi, gpt

I have a system with two storage disk that are GPT partitioned. One disk is installed with Ubuntu 16.04 and another with Ubuntu 18.04. Each has its own EFI System Partition (with boot and esp flags) and Swap, /, and /home partitions.

However, during UEFI booting, I only see the EFI boot partition of the Ubuntu 16.04 and not the EFI boot partition of both disks. Why is this so and how do I fix this?

Also, after editing the file `/etc/default/grub` in the Ubuntu 18.04 disk and the doing `sudo update-grub`, the changes did not take effect. Eg. I tried to add a GRUB_BACKGROUND, it did not appear. Similar changes made in `/etc/default/grub` file found in the Ubuntu 16.04 do appear to take effect. What is going on here? How should I manage/edit Grub for a system having 2 storage GPT partitioned disks each installed with different Ubuntu distrubtion?

Note, while in Grub menu, I am able to see both Ubuntu distribitions and boot into them, they work.

Comment: Only one ESP is seen/used. In order to use the other one you would need to change the drive boot order. That's why we generally DON'T use two ESPs. UEFI systems are supposed to have only one regardless of the number of OSes installed.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I am not able to change the boot order. As mentioned in 2nd para, the UEFI only showed the EFI boot partition of the disk with Ubuntu 16.04 to boot from, and the EFI boot partition of the disk with Ubuntu 18.04 did not appear in the UEFI. Why is this so and how do I fix this?

Comment: You need to read the user's manual, perhaps. The boot order in UEFI is set from the ESP in the first drive, a different and independent setting. The problem seems to be your lack of understanding of how this works, also probably the reason why you think you need another ESP, therefore this is a problem entirely of your own doing.